# Handler error while trying to execute Jetty Server

Tags: java, servlets, import, server, jetty

I get error: `incompatible types: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler cannot be converted to org.mortbay.jetty.Handler`
While trying to run my below code. I'm new to Java and not sure why this is happening. Any ideas? (I'm using JDK 11 and the latest Jetty versions 9.3 and IDE IntelliJ)

```
package newJetty;

import newJetty.handler.PingHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;
import org.mortbay.jetty.Handler;
import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class JettyServer
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();

        handler.addServletWithMapping(PingHandler.class, "/ping");
        server.setHandler(handler);
        //

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: The latest version is not Jetty 9.3, it's Jetty 9.4.14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing the wrong classes.

Remove the imports:

```
import org.mortbay.jetty.Handler;
import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
```

and change to the following imports:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
```